# Factors regarding menu visibility (menu is missing on access denied)

Tags: users, routes

I've built a theme based on Zen starterkit, and recently noticed that my main menu is not rendering on any access denied pages (non-admin role obviously), however, the remaining content is rendered as expected. What are the likely causes & recommended solutions? Is this a Zen thing?

Comment: Ugh, never-mind, just a CSS issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you're ever missing something in your site, consider these factors when diagnosing:

- check the raw markup itself (HTML) ensure it's not a CSS issue.
- a permissions problem, does the role have access?
- can you narrow the problem to the theme... this will determine further courses of action